# custom exceptions in Python don't seem to follow the "its easier to ask for forgiveness"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, error-handling

I'm trying to improve my coding and recently came across custom exceptions and the concept of "Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" (EAFP) but it doesn't seem to me that custom exceptions still follow this concept.

For example, in the code below, A looks clean but no custom exception. B also looks clean but no custom exception and does not follow EAFP concept. An alternative to B is replace KeyError with a custom error. C has a custom exception but it seems pretty verbose and for me, it almost seems closer to LBYL.

Is example C typically how custom exceptions are used? (with try/except AND if/else)

Are the extra lines of code in example C worth it for production-grade code that many people will use?

```
animal_dict={'cat':'mammal', 
             'dog':'mammal', 
             'lizard':'reptile'}

# A - easier to ask for forgiveness not permission (EAFP)
try:
    animal_type = animal_dict['hamster']
except KeyError:
    print('Your animal cannot be found')


#B - look before you leap (LBYL)
if 'hamster' in animal_dict:
    animal_type = animal_dict['hamster']
else:
    raise KeyError('Your animal cannot be found')


# C - with custom exception
class AnimalNotFoundError(KeyError):
    pass

try:
    if 'hamster' in animal_dict:
        animal_type = animal_dict['hamster']
    else:
        raise AnimalNotFoundError('Invalid animal: {}'.format('hamster'))
except AnimalNotFoundError as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: you would never raise an exception just to catch in in the same code block, though.

Comment: Not true.  I often find it convenient to catch AssertionError in unittests, do something (log? inspect?) then raise it right back up. True, I did not implicitly raise it but I might have reasons to elsewhere.

Comment: *Are the extra lines of code in example C worth it for production-grade code that many people will use?* It really depends on the complexity of the codebase and how you want to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you should use your custom exception to add detail to generic `KeyError` exception.  You can use the `from` keyword within the exception handling block to associate your exception to the base exeption, like so:

```
class AnimalNotFoundError(KeyError):
    pass

try:
    # Don't look, just take
    animal_type = animal_dict['hamster']
except KeyError as ex:
    # Add some detail for the error here, and don't silently consume the error
    raise AnimalNotFoundError('Invalid animal: {}'.format('hamster')) from ex
```

Comment: +1.  Do keep in mind that lots of custom subclassed exceptions can be a pain if your whole code stack needs to be aware of them.  For example, dbapi2-related SQL function calls are usually wonderfully detailed, but your client code isn't aware of what a library's `OperationalError` is, unless it specifically imported it, or unless it knows which subclass to test it against.  This gets worse when your client code is firing against a generic cursor, but now isn't sure if its a mysql or a postgres library doing the work.

Comment: You could just as well intercept the KeyError, set `ex.myinfo = 'Invalid animal: {}'.format('hamster')` and raise it again.  It all depends if AnimalNotFoundError is intended to have key meaning throughout your code, in which case its declaration probably belongs in its own module.

Comment: @JLPeyret - I agree, many libraries have way too complex hierarchical exception layouts with little obvious benefit.  I try to limit this style of exception to cases when I can add valuable detail to opaque problems.

Comment: and I'd give you another +1 for the `from` here, will have to look into its semantics, but looks nifty.